# How to combine (join?) two overlapping polygons to determine combined area they cover?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, polygon, area, merge

How do I combine (join?) two overlapping polygons to determine the combined area they cover in ArcGIS 10?

I am sure the Geoprocessing tools can do it, but just how eludes me.

Comment: I think this Question needs to have a diagram added to make what it is asking clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for the [Dissolve](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000005n000000) tool - if all of your polygons are in the same featureclass/layer just run it and then use the [Field Calculator](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s00000026000000) to determine the area.

If your polygons are in different featureclasses, run the [Merge](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000055000000) or [Append](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000050000000) tool first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know I'm nearly there not just quite yet. I have merged the polygons, but I can't seem to figure out what the Dissolve tool does. The merged polygon's attribute table only features the individual areas for the original polygons...

Comment: I"m actually surprised that's the answer. If you're looking for the area of overlap of 2 overlapping polygons, I would think that Intersect would be your tool of choice.

Comment: @Clickinaway - Given how the question was phrased ("combine (join?) two overlapping polygons"), Dissolve seemed like the most suitable answer.